# Why Spring's ProfileCondition.matches method cast value(Object) to String[] type?

Tags: java, spring

```
class ProfileCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> attrs = metadata.getAllAnnotationAttributes(Profile.class.getName());
    if (attrs != null) {
        for (Object value : attrs.get("value")) {
            if (context.getEnvironment().acceptsProfiles((String[]) value)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

As you can see, ProfileCondition fetches all annotation attributes for @Profile annotation from AnnotationTypeMetadata. In Profile class, value defined as `String[] value();` So, `for (Object value : attrs.get("value")` means value is a String parameter, but why is it cast to String[] type?

Comment: `value` *must* be a `String[]`, otherwise a `ClassCastException` would be thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is to look at the data structure you're querying. `attrs` is a `MultiValueMap`, or a data structure that maps a key (in this case a `String`) to some number of values (in this case each of type `Object`). `attrs.get` returns the set of values to which a specific key is mapped. Therefore, `attrs.get` returns a list of Objects, `List<Object>`. Since we're querying `"values"`, the list returned consists of a single `Object`, which is actually type `String[]`. However, since the `MultiValueMap` stores values of several different types, the value type of the map must be a common ancestor class: `Object`.

To summarize, `attrs.get` can feasibly return multiple results and therefore returns an iterable. For the key `"values"`, it's return type is (effectively) `List<String[]>`. We iterate through the iterable, and at each iteration of the for-loop, `value` is of type `String[]` and is downcast as such.

Comment: Thank you, I confused `MultiValueMap<String, Object>`'s `Object` at first. Now, I realized the `Object` is "muti map value" rather than `String[]`. But I still confused why `getAllAnnotationAttributes` method return a map in which some key maps muti values. Surely it doesn't mean that  there are more than one field named "value" in `Profile` annotation class?

Comment: From the documentation: "Note that this variant does not take attribute overrides into account." It therefore returns all definitions of the attribute, instead of taking into account overrides to return a single attribute.